# ¿Cómo guardar Lista dentro de modelo de MongoDB desde Android Studio con Retrofit2?

Tags: android-studio, nodejs, mongoose, post, retrofit

estoy intentando a partir de un formulario de registro de usuarios y una petición @POST poder guardar en una bbdd MongoDB, manejada en un servidor node.js, un modelo-esquema de datos como este:

```
{
    nombre: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        match: /^[\w-\.]+@([\w- ]+\.)+[\w- ]{2,4}$/
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
       },
    preference: [{
        nombre: {
            type: String,
            trim: true,
            required: true
        },
        color: {
            type: String,
            enum: ['Negro', 'Blanco', 'Azul', 'Rojo', 'Gris'],
            required: false
        }

    }]

}
```

Para ello estoy usando retrofit2 en AndroidStudio. En la interfaz de mi servicio he creado esta petición POST:

```
   @POST("/api/users/register")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<RegisterResult> executeRegister (@Field("nombre") String nombre,
                                @Field("email") String email,
                                @Field("password") String password,
                                @Field("preference") ArrayList<Preference> preference);
```

El problema me surge con la Lista preference, ya que aún creándola según las preferencias seleccionadas en el registro de usuarios de mi app Android al hacer click en registrar, el servidor me lanza este error:

```
Error: user validation failed: preference: Cast to embedded failed for value "`"Preference{nombre='Electronica', color='null'}"`" at path "preference"
    at ValidationError.inspect (\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validation.js:47:26)
    at internal/per_context/primordials.js:23:32
    at formatValue (internal/util/inspect.js:783:19)
    at inspect (internal/util/inspect.js:337:10)
    at formatWithOptionsInternal (internal/util/inspect.js:2016:40)
    at formatWithOptions (internal/util/inspect.js:1898:10)
    at console.value (internal/console/constructor.js:323:14)
    at console.log (internal/console/constructor.js:358:61)
    at newUser (\src\controllers\users.js:30:29)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

Como datos adicionales puedo añadir que uso `.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())` para el cliente Retrofit.

He intentado ya de muchas formas la posibilidad de guardar la lista de preferencias pero no lo consigo. Además, si no selecciono ninguna preferencia sí que se registran usuarios, pero con ese campo vacío (obviamente).

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logré resolver la cuestión, fue más sencillo de lo que pensaba estando en el punto que estaba.

Simplemente hay que pasar como parámetro de la llamada @POST un @Body de la clase .java creada con todos los argumentos del registro. Luego, el `.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())` realizará toda la conversión a formato JSON para que el cliente retrofit pueda enviar los datos al servidor.

Espero que le sirva de ayuda a alguien que se encuentre con mi mismo problema.